# Asynchronous execution with datastax mapper

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Can we execute batch statements with Datastax mapper for Cassandra (Java driver) ? I want to execute a batch statement asynchronously without getting blocked for the result. Are there any examples?

Answer (score 2):

The [Mapper](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/mapping/Mapper.html) interface has asynchronous variants of the basic operations (`saveAsync`, etc.)

If you're using accessors, specify a return type of `ResultSetFuture` or `ListenableFuture<T>` to make the query asynchronous. Here's an example [from our tests](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.1/driver-mapping/src/test/java/com/datastax/driver/mapping/MapperTest.java#L275):

```
// Note that the following method will be asynchronous (it will use executeAsync
// underneath) because it's return type is a ListenableFuture. Similarly, we know
// that we need to map the result to the Post entity thanks to the return type.
@Query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id=?")
@QueryParameters(consistency="QUORUM")
public ListenableFuture<Result<Post>> getAllAsync(UUID userId);
```